# Is there a way to log the keras model summary to neptune?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neptune

I am working on a CNN project and I would like to log the model.summary to neptune.ai. The intention of that is to have an idea about the model parameters while comparing different models. Any help/tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log `model.summary` (assuming it's keras), like this:

```
neptune.init('workspace/project')
neptune.create_experiment()

model = keras.Sequential(...)
model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: neptune.log_text('model_summary', x))
```

This will log entire summary as lines of text. You can later browse it in the *Logs* section of the experiment. Look for tile: "model_summary" in this [example](https://ui.neptune.ai/o/USERNAME/org/example-project/e/HELLO-325/logs).

Another option - for easier compare - is to log hyper-parameters at experiment creation, like this:

```
# Define parameters as Python dict
PARAMS = {'batch_size': 64,
          'n_epochs': 100,
          'shuffle': True,
          'activation': 'elu'}

# Pass PARAMS dict to params at experiment creation
neptune.create_experiment(params=PARAMS)
```

You will have them in *Parameters* tab of the experiment, like in this [example](https://ui.neptune.ai/o/USERNAME/org/example-project/e/HELLO-44/parameters). You will be able to add each parameter as a column to the dashboard for quick compare. Look for greenish columns in this [dashboard](https://ui.neptune.ai/o/USERNAME/org/example-project/experiments?viewId=d7f80ebe-5bfe-4d12-97c1-2b1e6184a2ed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first option is really interesting, I will try it. I am looking more into the 2nd option so that I can compare the parameters. the slight issue there is that the paras dict should be manually maintained. I  have now found a way to export the Keras model summary to dict data and pass this into the Neptune callback